# Can I swap hard drive between two identical PCs and keep all installed programs and OS intact?

Tags: hard-drive, desktop-computer, swap

I have two Dell Precision T7600 desktop computers. I have all my programs installed on PC1 using Windows 10 OS. If I swap the hard drive, will all the installed programs, OS (Windows 10 and Ubuntu) as well as drivers work on PC2?

Do I need to reinstall drivers for webcam, spectrum analyzer, etc. that I never used on PC2?

Specifications: 
Processor: Intel (R) Xeon (R) CPU E5-2630 0 @ 2.30GHz 2.30GHz
RAM:       16 GB
OS:        Windows 10

N.B. The OS is a licensed version that my university offers to current students.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Even if you transfer the hdd, due to how USB works, even if its the exact same Windows installation it will act like it never saw the device.  Just how USB devices work.   The driver will be found but initially it will install the device

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably start by pointing out that your licence may *not* allow you to swap the disks. Assuming you have a retail edition, and you have the right hardware drivers for PC2 (or they're fundamentally identical), it should work. Things like architecture (single processor vs multiprocessor, intel vs amd) matter, but these should be the same for the same model.

At *most* you'd have to reactivate. I wouldn't recommend *routinely* swapping drives between machines for that reason but the system would likely boot up at least far enough to log in and check.

Comment: Windows 10 keeps its activation in BIOS, so it will spot difference.

Comment: I downloaded and installed a licensed version of "Windows 10 Pro" that my university offers to its current students. I have the activation key for future use. Does Pro edition allow swapping the disks?

Comment: @Alex The Windows 10 license he is using isn't stored in the ACPI table thought.  Licenses are not stored in the BIOS, the ACPI table, is something else.

Comment: @SalmanShokha Link both of your licenses to a Microsoft Account.  If you do this, Windows won't complain, and won't deactivate

Comment: AH, no, your install *should* be locked to your hardware. That said, this shouldn't be any different from a one off motherboard replacement no?

Comment: @Ramhound PC2 only has Linux installed, no Windows there.

Comment: My comment doesn't change.  Hardware is similar enough activation won't complain if you link the license to the MS account

Comment: I guess the main problem here, as I see it, is whether the license can be transferred. And that depends on the exact edition

Comment: @JourneymanGeek AFAIK, besides of key stored in ACPI table(Ramhound is correct, I oversimplified it) windows using 7 points(MAC addr, serials from hdd, memory and something else, don't remember exactly) to identify current computer, if more than 3 points are changed, then windows will through red flag.

Comment: Hence the need to *reactivate* - retail will let you move it, and dreamspark's the same as retail. That it would blue screen, as per your answer is not accurate.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Agree, but on the moment I wrote my answer, there no any information about even version of Windows :) What should I do in such cases(edit my post?), could you point me please

Answer (score 1):

Swapping drives between two PCs, usually not identically spec'd, has worked for me consistently with ArchLinux and with Windows 7, 8, and 10.  Windows XP has given me issues.  The one thing that occurs when doing this is that Windows will go through a "repair" process prior to booting to the desktop on its first boot upon swapping.  You will also want to make sure you have a record of the product key for your computer, be it through your Windows COA on your case or elsewhere, to reactivate on your new desktop.

Answer (score 0):

It will work, but you might have problems reactivating the Windows license.  I've done it lots of times with Windows XP and Windows 7, but never with Windows 10.  If you have any PCI cards, you'll get best results if they are in identical slots.
If you have MS Office installed, you'll need to reactivate that license as well.

Ubuntu should give you no problems at all.

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu should work, <del>but windows will get you blue screen of death.</del>
but Windows would need to be reactivated.

You don't need to reinstall drivers on Ubuntu it will install drivers  automatically if needed.

If you have an extra license, you can reactivate Windows on PC2, but even if computer are identical, I would go with official way of transferring OS to another computer by using `sysprep`

Comment: They're mostly identical machines though

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes, but Windows activation glued to multiple hardware IDs and BIOS

Comment: Wouldn't blue screen tho. It would complain about activation.

Comment: Even with hardware that isn't the same, it's still possible, for Windows to boot.  Having the installation activated is the real challenge.  Automatic activation will only be done so many times.